# Rewrite WordPress permalink URL using mod_rewrite breaks Archive

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite

The following mod_rewrite rule accomplishes the task of rewriting `www.domain.com/2011/11/page` to `www.domain.com/page` but breaks `www.domain.com/2011/11/` (i.e. breaks WordPress Archive listings) and redirects it to the root of the site.

The rewrite rule should only rewrite items that have content after `^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/page` but not `^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/`.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.*)$ /$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Any recommendations?

**ANSWER**

The initial forward slash was missing at the beginning:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ /$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

and the WordPress permalink entry needed:

```
/%postname%/
```

instead of:

```
%postname%
```

although I am not sure how much the latter helped.

Comment: I anwsered a bit later but I did not have enough points to answer my own questions within 8 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the * to a +

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.*)$ /$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

should be

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.+)$ /$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

With (.*), it could possibly match nothing, thus a request like "/2011/11/" will match but the back reference for (.*) will be blank, thus the rewrite goes to "/". The **+** indicates that there needs to be at least 1 character satisfying the "." in the regular expression.

Comment: The `*` actually works though I was just unable to answer my own question in time but I'll give you credit ;-)